# Can I benefit from cover against an effect that destroys that cover?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cover

The [*wall of ice*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-ice) spell creates a destructible wall, with each 10-foot section having 30 hit points:

> The wall is an object that can be damaged and thus breached. It has AC 12 and 30 hit points per 10-foot section, and it is vulnerable to fire damage. Reducing a 10-foot section of wall to 0 hit points destroys it and leaves behind a sheet of frigid air in the space the wall occupied.

Suppose a *fireball* spell detonates on the opposite side of the wall from me, such that the wall provides total cover against it. However, the *fireball* deals 27 fire damage, which is enough to destroy any sections of the wall caught in the blast (since the wall is vulnerable to fire damage). So, the *fireball* will definitely destroy my cover. So *before* the *fireball*, I definitely have cover, while afterward I definitely don't have cover any more. However, it's not clear whether I still have full cover against the effect of the *fireball* itself.

More generally, **in any case where I have cover against an effect but the effect itself destroys that cover, do I gain the benefit of that cover before it is destroyed, or does the cover get destroyed before I can benefit from it?**